# Python Regex - Match and Start()

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Let's say I need to find the word "water" in a string. This word cannot be part of another word and it can't be preceded by punctuation (so i'm assuming it can only be preceded by a " " or it's the beginning of the string). 
I need to return the index of the word's first char "w". So I'm trying this code :

```
import re
s = re.search(r"(\A| )\bwater\b", "Need water") 
return s.start() # This returns the index of the char " " :(
```

Is it possible to ignore the **(\A| )** part of the pattern so that s.start() always returns the index of the char "w"? Or am I thinking this wrong?

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)\bwater\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\S)\bwater\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eT5vS1/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!\S)` - a negative lookbehind failing a match if there is a non-whitespace character right before a whole word `water`
- `\bwater\b` - a whole word `water`.

Here is a [Python demo](http://ideone.com/vy1li5):

```
import re
s = re.search(r"(?<!\S)\bwater\b", "Need water") 
if s:
    print(s.start())
```

Comment: That's absolutely right!! Thank you so much! So it matches the string if it is not preceded by \S. And the negative lookbehind isn't considered in the start()

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have that "beginning of a string or space" check. You've already applied the word boundaries check:

```
>>> s = re.search(r"\bwater\b", "Need water")
>>> s.start()
5
>>> s = re.search(r"\bwater\b", "water is needed")
>>> s.start()
0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately I don't want to match cases like ".water". I don't want it to be preceded by any chars (only " ").

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need regex. Just match the space and the word, that will get you the character that the space is at, but you want the first letter so add 1

```
bigString = "I drink water"

if " " not in bigString:
    print(bigString.find("water"))
else:
    print(bigString.find(" water")+1)
```